# AngularJs 1.2 Two way binding vs Factory service

Tags: angularjs, service, binding, factory, two-way

I'm trying to find a way that I can share data between directives within a page. Like:

Parent
--Child
----GrandChild
--Child
----GrandChild

Child is same directive being reused and Grandchild might have smaller directives inside.
 My first attempt was using Two way binding between Child and Grandchild, but I see most people use Factory to share data so I wonder which method is better?
If I want to go with using Factory, how can I make each Child their own Factory services?

Comment: I would stick with 2 way binding.  A factory or service is used more to share data between pages (controllers) rather than directives contained on the same page and presumably the same controller.

Comment: I think in this situation 2 way data binding is a better approach. A Factory is a Singleton, so I don't think that it's a very good approach to share data between multiple directives in the same page, depends on you structure this can get very complex.